# how to print text/html file using dot matrix printer via USB in android?

Tags: android, printing

is it possible to print html/text file using dot matrix printer via USB in android.
or if there is any app that support monochrome (black and write) deskjet printers via USB
any one have idea please help me.

thanks in advance.